# What could be the cause of 'Could not find installable ISAM' error in my code?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2007

I can't figure out why I am getting an error here saying: `Could not find installable ISAM`. I am trying to add data to Access file which seems to have a problem.

I'm not sure why this wouldn't work since I am using almoust exacting code when deleting each entry.

Is there any obvious errors here?

```
        // Creating a query for each type of data.
        string sqlPC = @"INSERT INTO PersonalData([Type], [UserName], [Password]) 
                         VALUES(@Type, @UserName, @Password)";
        string sqlWS = @"INSERT INTO PersonalData([Type], [URL], [UserName], [Password]) 
                         VALUES(@Type, @URL, @UserName, @Password)";
        string sqlSC = @"INSERT INTO PersonalData([Type], [SoftwareName], [SerialCode]) 
                         VALUES(@Type, @SoftwareName, @SerialCode)";

    HashPhrase hashPhrase = new HashPhrase();
    Security security = new Security();

    private void InsertData(string sql)
    {
        string hashShortPass = hashPhrase.ShortHash(pass);

        string connectionString = 
            @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0};
              Persist Security Info=False; Jet OLEDB: Database Password={1};";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = 
                string.Format(connectionString, filePath, hashShortPass);

            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                OleDbParameter prmType = new OleDbParameter
                    ("@Type", security.EncryptAES(cmbType.Text, pass, user));

                command.Parameters.Add(prmType);

                if (cmbType.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    OleDbParameter prmUserName = new OleDbParameter
                        ("@UserName", security.EncryptAES
                            (txtUserName.Text.Trim(), pass, user));
                    OleDbParameter prmPassword = new OleDbParameter
                        ("@Password", security.EncryptAES
                            (txtPassword.Text, pass, user));

                    command.Parameters.Add(prmUserName);
                    command.Parameters.Add(prmPassword);
                }
                else if (cmbType.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    OleDbParameter prmURL = new OleDbParameter
                        ("@URL", security.EncryptAES
                            (txtURL.Text.Trim(), pass, user));
                    OleDbParameter prmUserName = new OleDbParameter
                        ("@UserName", security.EncryptAES
                            (txtUserName.Text.Trim(), pass, user));
                    OleDbParameter prmPassword = new OleDbParameter
                        ("@Password", security.EncryptAES
                            (txtPassword.Text, pass, user));

                    command.Parameters.Add(prmURL);
                    command.Parameters.Add(prmUserName);
                    command.Parameters.Add(prmPassword);
                }
                else if (cmbType.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    OleDbParameter prmSoftwareName = new OleDbParameter
                        ("@SoftwareName", security.EncryptAES
                            (txtSoftwareName.Text.Trim(), pass, user));
                    OleDbParameter prmSerialCode = new OleDbParameter
                        ("@SerialCode", security.EncryptAES
                            (txtSerialCode.Text.Trim(), pass, user));

                    command.Parameters.Add(prmSoftwareName);
                    command.Parameters.Add(prmSerialCode);
                }

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The ACE provider is not properly installed on your machine.  Arbitrarily try re-installing it, ask for more help on superuser.com.  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23734

Comment: @Hans Passant: If that would be the case, why I can delete an entry, but cannot add one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed:

```
string connectionString = 
            @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0};
              Persist Security Info=False; Jet OLEDB: Database Password={1};";
```

To:

```
string connectionString = 
            @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0};
              Persist Security Info=False; Jet OLEDB:Database Password={1};";
```

And it works, I have had 1 unneeded space...

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i Fixed so:

I change:

```
string conexion = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\temp\Fa.mdb;Database Password=xxx;";
```

to:

```
string conexion = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\temp\Fa.mdb;Persist Security Info=False; Jet OLEDB:Database Password='xxx';";
```

Answer (score 0):

For the insert part you have a field named Password which is a keyword in MS Access. Your insert statement should include [Password] instead of Password.

Comment: Yes, I am doing the brackets to avoid problems with reserved words.

Comment: If password is in brackets then try using command.Parameters.AddWithValue("", value); directly.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i changed

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\\Export.accdb;Database Password=123"
```

as

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\\Export.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123"
```

and it works...